# Updating millions of records in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I think this will be easier to explain by including a couple of tables.

Table A:

```
UserId     StoreId
1          10
2          20
3          30
4          40
```

Table B:

```
UserId     StoreId
1          10
1          20
1          20
2          20
2          10
2          10
3          30
3          40
3          40
4          40
4          30
4          30
```

I need a script that will go into Table 2, and Update the store to match the `StoreId` in Table A for that specific User. In the end, I should see;

Table B:

```
UserId     StoreId
1          10
1          10
1          10
2          20
2          20
2          20
3          30
3          30
3          30
4          40
4          40
4          40
```

So my question is, what is the easiest way to do this, considering that Table B has hundred of millions of rows in it, and table A has about 20 million rows?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_B
DROP COLUMN StoreId
```

Now you're no longer storing duplicate data and you can just get the `StoreId` from `Table_A` when you need it.

Otherwise it's just a simple `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE B
SET
    StoreId = A.StoreID
FROM
    Table_B B
INNER JOIN TABLE_A A ON A.UserId = B.UserId
```

You can put this into a loop that performs batches if you need to in order to cut down on the size of the update so that it doesn't flood your transaction log. There are a few ways to do that. One example:

```
DECLARE
    @batch_size INT = 10000,
    @min_user_id INT = 1,
    @max_user_id INT

SELECT @max_user_id = MAX(UserId) FROM Table_A

WHILE (@min_user_id <= @max_user_id)
BEGIN
    UPDATE B
    SET
        StoreId = A.StoreID
    FROM
        Table_B B
    INNER JOIN TABLE_A A ON A.UserId = B.UserId
    WHERE
        B.UserId BETWEEN @min_user_id AND @min_user_id + @batch_size

    SET @min_user_id = @min_user_id + @batch_size + 1
END
```

Comment: I wish I could just go in and drop that column, but I came on to this project many years after it was created. It would require quite a few changes to the front end website, as well as our EDMX, to go in and drop unnecessary columns at this point. 

Great answer though! I appreciate the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 1 
while (@@rowcount > 0) 
begin
    UPDATE top(1000) B
    SET b.StoreId = A.StoreID 
    FROM Table_B B
    INNER JOIN TABLE_A A ON A.UserId = B.UserId 
    where b.StoreId <> A.StoreID 
       or b.StoreId is null
end
```